# Get Random Url from website

Tags: php, parsing

I want to search number of links or URL on http://public-domain-content.com
and store them in an array and then just randomly select any one from array and just display or echo

How can i do that in php

Comment: What do you mean you want to select URL random? Your question isn't very descriptive.

Comment: So you want to know how many URL there are in a given page and then choose one randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you're asking, you can achieve this using `file_get_contents();`

After using `file_get_contents($url)`, which gives you a string, you can loop through the result string searching for spaces to tell the words apart. Count the number of words, and store the words in an array accordingly. Then just choose a random element from the array using `array_rand()`

However, sometimes there are security problems with `file_get_contents()`.
You can override this using the following function:

```
function get_url_contents($url)
{
    $crl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);

    return $ret;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php <--- Explanation about curl

Example code:

```
$url = "http://www.xxxxx.xxx";     //Set the website you want to get content from
$str = file_get_contents($url);    //Get the contents of the website
$built_str = "";                   //This string will hold the valid URLs

$strarr = explode(" ", $str);      //Explode string into array(every space a new element)

for ($i = 0; $i < count($strarr); $i++)  //Start looping through the array
{
    $current = @parse_url($strarr[$i])   //Attempt to parse the current element of the array

    if ($current)                        //If parse_url() returned true(URL is valid)
    {
        $built_str .= $current . " ";    //Add the valid URL to the new string with " "
    }

    else
    {
        //URL invalid. Do something here
    }

}

$built_arr = explode(" ", $built_str)   //Same as we did with $str_arr. This is why we added a space to $built_str every time the URL was valid. So we could use it now to split the string into an array

echo $built_arr[array_rand($built_arr)]; // Display a random element from our built array
```

There is also a more extended version to checking URLs, which you can explore here:

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=326016

Good luck.

Comment: The structure I wrote in my answer is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: It would be great if you explain code briefly and is there any check to take only valid urls not adds on page